# EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs' error after NodeJS Upgrade

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, travis-ci

I upgraded one of my NodeJS services from 12 to 16 and then I started to get this error on Travis build.

```
 glob error [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'] {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/root/.npm/_logs'
}
```

My .travis.yml file looks like that:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 16

services:
  - docker

cache:
  yarn: true
  directories:
    - node_modules

before_install:
  - curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash -s
  - export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$PATH"

before_script:
  - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin

script:
  - docker-compose run persistence-api npm run test:ci
  - npm run dist
.....
```

Does anyone have an idea about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I disabled the cache with `false` values specifically and also removed the `before_install` part. Added `install:skip` and changed the script. You can see the new command on the script below. These changes worked for me after spending hours on the topic.

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 16

services:
  - docker

# disable cache due to problems on cached node_modules which are not fixed by `yarn --frozen-lockfile`
cache:
  npm: false
  yarn: false

install: skip

before_script:
  - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin

script:
  - docker-compose run persistence-api sh -c "yarn install --ignore-optional && yarn pretest && yarn test"
  - npm run dist
  ........
```